# If I have struct inside another struct and I am trying to have them inside an array

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct that is named `item`, now I have another struct that is called `array` that calls `item`. The `struct item arrayofList`is required to be of the size `5`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MaxItems 5
#define NameLength 20
#define UnitLenght 6



struct item
{
    char name[NameLength];
    float amount;
    char unit[UnitLenght];
};
struct array
{
    struct item arrayofList;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct array shopping[MaxItems];
```

Am I giving the list size of 5 or am I doing it incorrectly

Comment: I think you just want `struct LIST shopping[MaxItems];`, and drop `struct array` alltogether. Then `shopping` is an array  of `MaxItems` `struct LIST`s. And I think `struct LIST` is ill-named, it should be named `struct item`.

Comment: But anyway, maybe you should just tell us what you're trying to achieve. Read this: [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: so I cant have it in main `struct array item[MaxItems];`?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: You don't need `struct array` at all. With your edited question you just want `struct item shopping[MaxItems];` and remove the `struct array` definition.

Comment: ok Will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MaxItems 5
#define NameLength 20
#define UnitLenght 6

struct item  // one item
{
    char name[NameLength];
    float amount;
    char unit[UnitLenght];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct item shopping[MaxItems];  // array of MaxItems struct items
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted `struct array` to contain an array of 5 `LIST`s, you would declare it as follows:

```
struct array
{
    struct LIST arrayofList[MaxItems];
};
```

and then just use it as

```
int main(void)
{
    struct array shopping;
```

But I will agree with the Jabberwock, currently this `struct array` is superfluous and you could achieve the same functionality by removing `struct array` altogether and using an array of `LIST` directly instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct LIST shopping[MaxItems];
```

Unless you intend on eventually adding more attributes to `struct array`, this would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need the struct array? You can just write:
`struct item shopping[MaxItems];`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, you cannot comment until you have 50 points of rep.